# Is there any way to compile py scripts to pyc as Python 2.7 from a 3.7 script?

Tags: python-3.x, pyc

I would like to:

from a python 3.7 scripts 
    do a compileall.compile_dir('.')

to create pyc's of quite many scripts written in 2.7

I am now getting syntax errors against 3.7. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot and HappyNY!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convert the syntaxis of the python 2.7 scripts to python 3.7 using [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)
Afterwards i expect your procedure to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. We have dozens of 2.7 scripts that we will be converting gradually, but not at once. The deployment script I am writing is 3.7 so I am trying to deal with this transition situation and was wondering whether py -> pyc compilation in 2.7 from a 3.7 script was possible.